# CSS to make a container with a border disappear when all of its contents are hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a common need that arises from my experience making quick and dirty menus.

You have a container that has some styling (box shadow... border...), and dynamically inside of it are elements.

When the container is empty, I want the container to disappear rather than render a degenerate shape with the style.

This is readily and (more or less elegantly) achieved via the use of something like `container:empty { display: none; }`.

The problem really takes its true form when you have a hierarchy of these types of containers. Consider:

```
<div>
  <span id=b></span>
  <span id=a></span>
<div>
```

Both spans are empty containers, and they do not have their styles drawn since we have a nice `:empty` style that makes them `display: none`.

However we are now unable to use the trick for the meta-container. The `:empty` pseudoelement style cannot make the spans cease to exist, so therefore the div is not considered to be empty.

The question is are there any clever CSS-isms that can mitigate this situation?

Are there any in the next upcoming CSS draft?

If both are not the case then what might be necessary to add it? This "incompleteness" is one of the biggest limitations of CSS as it is today.

I understand that it's not possible to know before scanning the children how to style the parent if spec is changed to allow any aspect of children to affect the parent, but could we not allow for the parent node one single chance to get re-styled at the END of parsing its children? Wouldn't that not even change the time complexity of the algorithm? (I realize how silly this is, as I am surely mega-simplifying it, but the point might still stand.)

Comment: Will the `<div>` ever have anything other than the `<span>` tags? Would a `height` of `0` be sufficient for the `<div>` if all the inner elements are empty?

Comment: @Intervalia the point is not HOW to hide it, which obviously can be done via any number of methods including setting height to zero, the point is to be able to SELECT the parent container with some kind of `:empty` that works even when it has children (which themselves happen to be empty)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do it via css. But you can use javascript:

```
$(".container:not(:has(:not(:empty)))").hide ();
```

Comment: OP didn't tag question with JQuery.

Comment: I don't mind jQuery answers at all (I stopped using it a while ago, but many people still do).

My concern with this is that this also doesn't cleanly scale to nesting/hierarchies, the jquery selector (which has more capability than pure CSS) still has its own corresponding nesting to deal with the structure.

Comment: The core of the problem is that CSS seems to be missing just a few little stretches that would make required javascript management much simpler.

Comment: I think (and I hope) that in the near future will be available CSS Level 4 selectors